# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityListeners

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Does anyone know what this error?

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at    presentation.utils.HibernateCommon.buildSessionFactory(HibernateCommon.java:39)
at presentation.utils.HibernateCommon.<clinit>(HibernateCommon.java:19)
at   filter.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.init(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3709)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4363)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:627)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:553)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1149)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityListeners
    at 
org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.getDefaults(JPAMetadataProvider.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.getDefaults(JavaReflectionManager.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1358)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1829)
    at presentation.utils.HibernateCommon.buildSessionFactory(HibernateCommon.java:35)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityListeners
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: Are you missing a jpa jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click [Here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar) to download hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar and put it into the project library, your application will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the `javax.persistence.jar` to your classpath.